# Perform Swap between textboxes without variables

Tags: vb.net

I was attending an interview, the interviewer asked me the question that: **Perform Swap between textboxes without variables.** i am familiar with `c/c++` concept of swap values without using temp, i tried them but it wont give me the result, can anyone suggest me how it become possible?

**Thanks in advance♥**

Comment: Easy - Put the data from both into one with a non printable character as a delimiter between them and then take the data before the delimiter into the other and the data from after into the first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some string handling functions we can easily **swap**(Interchanging) the contents of two text boxes. see the following code snippet :

```
 Private Sub btnSwap_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       TextBox2.Text &= TextBox1.Text
       TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0,TextBox2.Text.LastIndexOf(TextBox1.Text))
       TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "")
 End Sub
```

**How It Works:**

- Concatenate both texts and assign it into TextBox2
- Find the `SubString` based on the index of `TextBox1.Text` in the concatenated string which gives the `TextBox2.Text` and are assigned to the `TextBox1.Text`.
- Replace the `TextBox1.Text` from the Concatenated string will give the initial text in the `TextBox1.Text` which is assigned to the `TextBox2.Text`

**Example**

Let `TextBox1.Text="aaa"` and `TextBox2.Text="bbaaabb"`

**Step 1**: `TextBox2.Text= "aaabbaaabb"`

**step 2**: `TextBox1.Text= "bbaaabb"` ' since textbox2 contains `aaabbaaabb` and textbox1 contains `aaa`

**step 3**: `TextBox2.Text= "aaa"` 'since textbox2 contains `bbaaabb` and textbox1 contains `bbaaabb`

Comment: I would do a substring also for the last line. In case TextBox1 = "aaa" and TextBox2 = "bbaaabb"

Comment: @ the_lotus : see the edit(*add an example illustration*) to the answer

Comment: Sorry, I meant to other way around.    Step0: "bbbaaabbb", "aaa". Step1: "bbbaaabbb", "aaabbbaaabbb". Step2: "aaa", "aaabbbaaabbb". Step3: "aaa", "bbbbbb"